# What is the equivalent of "zip()" in Python's numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do the following but with numpy arrays:

```
x = [(0.1, 1.), (0.1, 2.), (0.1, 3.), (0.1, 4.), (0.1, 5.)]
normal_result = zip(*x)
```

This should give a result of:

```
normal_result = [(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), (1., 2., 3., 4., 5.)]
```

But if the input vector is a numpy array:

```
y = np.array(x)
numpy_result = zip(*y)
print type(numpy_result)
```

It (expectedly) returns a:

```
<type 'list'>
```

The issue is that I will need to transform the result back into a numpy array after this.

**What I would like to know is what is if there is an efficient numpy function that will avoid these back-and-forth transformations?**

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can just transpose it...

```
>>> a = np.array([(0.1, 1.), (0.1, 2.), (0.1, 3.), (0.1, 4.), (0.1, 5.)])
>>> a
array([[ 0.1,  1. ],
       [ 0.1,  2. ],
       [ 0.1,  3. ],
       [ 0.1,  4. ],
       [ 0.1,  5. ]])
>>> a.T
array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ]])
```

Comment: clever - nice to use maths

Answer (score 36):

Try using [dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = array([[1,2],[3,4]]) # shapes of a and b can only differ in the 3rd dimension (if present)
>>> b = array([[5,6],[7,8]])
>>> dstack((a,b)) # stack arrays along a third axis (depth wise)
array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6]],
       [[3, 7],
        [4, 8]]])
```

so in your case it would be:

```
x = [(0.1, 1.), (0.1, 2.), (0.1, 3.), (0.1, 4.), (0.1, 5.)]
y = np.array(x)
np.dstack(y)

>>> array([[[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
    [ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ]]])
```

Comment: Adds an extra dimension to a 2d array.  If you want something similar to what the OP wanted, you'll have to take the first element of the dstacked array.

Comment: Numpy np.stack is the closest to zip for matrices. `arrays = (x, y); np.stack(arrays, axis=len(arrays))`.

Comment: There is also np.column_stack, which may be what OP needs.

Comment: not exactly the correct answer but it's useful to know about