# How can I turn two lists of equal lengths into a list of nested lists that represent ordered pairs?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy, nested-lists

For example, if these are my two lists:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[6,7,8,9,10]
```

Then what I'm trying to do is to figure out a way to get:

```
c=[[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]
```

Sorry for the probably basic question. These are numpy arrays if that makes a difference.

Comment: This has potentially been answered before: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge lists into a list of tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of "zip()" in Python's numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744778/what-is-the-equivalent-of-zip-in-pythons-numpy)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a numpy array as a result, you can build it using `array.T`:

```
In [15]: a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [16]: b=np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

In [17]: np.array([a,b]).T
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

Reference: [What is the equivalent of "zip()" in Python's numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744778/what-is-the-equivalent-of-zip-in-pythons-numpy)

Answer (score 2):

I don't use numpy, but maybe by using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=[6,7,8,9,10]
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

It returns a list of tuples though.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using list comprehension and `zip`:

```
>>> [[i, j] for i, j in zip(a,b)]
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
>>> np.transpose([a, b])
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

If you want the result as list just call [`tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) afterwards:

```
>>> np.transpose([a, b]).tolist()
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = [list(x) for x in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: It looks like this will return a list of tuples and not a list of lists, but one can modify it using `map`, not sure if the best way, but: `list(map(list, zip(a, b)))` works well.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar You're right, I think the simplest and pythonic approach is just to do a list comprehension like `c = [list(x) for x in zip(a, b)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    d.append([a[i], b[i])
```

Is a simple way to create a new 2D list with element pairs. Using the zip() function as others have pointed out is also viable.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you just need to access the elements and not modify them, you can use the `zip` function:

```
zip(a, b)
>[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

If you actually need a list of lists, then you can use a list comprehension:

```
[[a[i], b[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
>[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

And finally, if you need a numpy array as a result, use the Transpose function:

```
import numpy as np
np.concatenate([[a], [b]]).T
>array([[1, 6],
        [2, 7],
        [3, 8],
        [4, 9],
        [5, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is an easier or more pythonic way than this.

`c = [list(x) for x in zip(a,b)]`

This outputs a list of lists, instead of just doing `list(zip(a,b)` that outputs a list of tuples. This combines list comprehension and zip

Also avoids the tuple unpacking of `[[i,j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]`

not sure whats more efficient though

`zip(*iterables)` Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0):

with no libraries, you could use:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = [[a[i],b[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```